# How to combine order by and group by together? condition : order by one column group by another column

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have one issue with order by and group by combination in MySQL.
Following is my table structure.

```
+-------------+-----------+-----------+----------------------------+
| driver_id   | lat       | lng       | creation                   |
+-------------+-----------+-----------+----------------------------+
| TDRV-000021 | 18.659180 | 73.756480 | 2019-03-13 09:21:39.225873 |
| TDRV-000021 | 18.659180 | 73.756480 | 2019-03-15 12:30:09.608296 |
| TDRV-000021 | 18.659135 | 73.756445 | 2019-03-10 15:38:37.954508 |
```

when I use the following SQL command (Order by Creation desc),

```
select driver_id, lat, lng, creation from `tabReal Time Location` order by creation desc;
```

I got the following result,

```
+-------------+-----------+-----------+----------------------------+
| driver_id   | lat       | lng       | creation                   |
+-------------+-----------+-----------+----------------------------+
| TDRV-000021 | 20.659180 | 73.756480 | 2019-03-16 08:13:41.155528 |
| TDRV-000021 | 18.659180 | 73.756480 | 2019-03-15 19:44:06.206690 |
| TDRV-000021 | 18.659180 | 73.756480 | 2019-03-15 19:36:25.571260 |
| TDRV-000021 | 18.659180 | 73.756480 | 2019-03-15 19:35:55.115124 |
| TDRV-000021 | 18.659180 | 73.756480 | 2019-03-15 19:35:46.281953 |
| TDRV-000021 | 18.659180 | 73.756480 | 2019-03-15 19:35:00.986849 |
| TDRV-000021 | 18.659180 | 73.756480 | 2019-03-15 19:33:38.370099 |
| TDRV-000021 | 18.659180 | 73.756480 | 2019-03-15 19:32:57.589272 |
| TDRV-000021 | 18.659180 | 73.756480 | 2019-03-15 19:30:24.582391 |
| TDRV-000021 | 18.659180 | 73.756480 | 2019-03-15 19:29:23.809564 |
```

and when I use to **combine order by and group by,**

```
select driver_id, lat, lng, creation from `tabReal Time Location` group by driver_id order by creation desc;

+-------------+-----------+-----------+----------------------------+
| driver_id   | lat       | lng       | creation                   |
+-------------+-----------+-----------+----------------------------+
| TDRV-000027 | 18.659180 | 73.756480 | 2019-03-15 13:47:37.338828 |
| TDRV-000021 | 18.659180 | 73.756480 | 2019-03-13 09:21:39.225873 |
+-------------+-----------+-----------+----------------------------+
```

but as you see in above result I'm getting the wrong result, I'm expecting **latest updated** **lat, lng** column-like below.

```
+-------------+-----------+-----------+----------------------------+
| driver_id   | lat       | lng       | creation                   |
+-------------+-----------+-----------+----------------------------+
| TDRV-000021 | 20.659180 | 73.756480 | 2019-03-16 08:13:41.155528 |
| TDRV-000027 | 20.659180 | 90.756480 | 2019-03-15 14:07:41.543089 |
+-------------+-----------+-----------+----------------------------+
```

Comment: Group by without aggregation is unlikely to produce a useful result. You could google mysql most recent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way for  expecting latest updated la

```
select t.driver_id, lat, lng, order_id  from `tabReal Time Location` t INNER JOIN  (select max(creation) as latest_date,driver_id  FROM `tabReal Time Location` group by  driver_id)d ON t.creation= d.latest_date and d.driver_id = t.driver_id;
```

Comment: Why did you use the convert function?

Comment: Join  on date column would  be Prefer instead of datetime or timestamp column